# Show toolbar above google map

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am having troubles in putting a **toolbar** above the google map.

I followed a online indication, but when I launch the code I am not able to see the toolbar.

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.namexxx.app.homemap"
/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, first you are using a framelayout and then telling the fragment:  android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
Use a relative layout instead of FrameLayout. Also can you change the height of your toolbar like this: 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected the code based on JPCrow inputs:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/SecondaryBackground"
tools:context="com.example.filippo.xxx.MainActivity"
>


<include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.filippo.xxx.homemap"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now it works. Thanks.